# Macro not executing itself completely

Tags: vba, excel, macros

So i have the following macro

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

BeginRow = 178
EndRow = 178
ChkCol = 8

For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
If IsError(Sheet1.Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value) Then
 Sheet1.Cells(169, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
 Sheet1.Cells(170, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
 Sheet1.Cells(171, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
 Sheet1.Cells(172, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
 Sheet1.Cells(173, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
 Sheet1.Cells(174, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
 Sheet1.Cells(175, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
 Sheet1.Cells(176, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
 Sheet1.Cells(177, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
 Sheet1.Cells(178, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
 Sheet1.Cells(179, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
Next RowCnt

For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
If Not IsError(Sheet1.Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value) Then
 Sheet1.Cells(169, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
 Sheet1.Cells(170, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
 Sheet1.Cells(171, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
 Sheet1.Cells(172, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
 Sheet1.Cells(173, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
 Sheet1.Cells(174, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
 Sheet1.Cells(175, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
 Sheet1.Cells(176, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
 Sheet1.Cells(177, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
 Sheet1.Cells(178, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
 Sheet1.Cells(179, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Next RowCnt
End Sub
```

You could probably do this a lot prettier, but i am quite new to VBA.
The formula H178 has the following input:

```
`=(H170+H171+H172+H173+H174+H175+H176+H177)/7`
```

However these cells H170, H171 etc. get their data from Sheet2
So i.e. when H170 is an error, H178 gives a #REF! which should automatically mean that the macro is runned, but it doesn't, unless if i double-click on the cell H178 and hit enter.

But if i i.e. change the cell H170 directly on sheet1, to =5/0 (which gives error) then the macro is runned.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You want the Worksheet_Calculate() event not the Worksheet_Change event

Comment: See 'Remarks' here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx

Comment: Also to combine all the lines: `Sheet1.Rows("169:179").Hidden = True`

Comment: 3 things: Have you definately put it in sheet1 calculate event rather than sheet2, is calculation on manual? Try a forced application.calculate in the sheet2.change event

Answer (score 1):

You should place this code in the Worksheet_Calculate event in order to have it recalculate when the error is passed

Comment: So i tried using Worksheet_Calculate() instead, but i can't really seem to test it, since the Excel now freezes when i change a cell.

Comment: Likely stuck in an infinite loop caused by changeEvents (essentially it is changing the content and then seeing that something changed so it is relaunching the code and changing the content and seeing something changed...... ad infinitum).  Try adding "Application.Events = False" at the top of your code, and True at the end

Comment: So i tried adding those, but got a Run-Time error 438.
However, removing the top one "Application.Events = False" Makes the macro work, but it still gives run-time error 438, so i just click "End". Any way to get rid of that?

Comment: The "Application.Events = True" gives the error. seems weird to me that it works, but still gives error.

Worked for 5 mins. Now excel starts shutting down itself.

Comment: Im a dope :(  should be "EnableEvents" not "Events"-